# Como colocar uma div que está dentro de um Container, embaixo uma da outra?

Tags: html, css, html5, jsp

Estou com o seguinte problema, minha Divs estão ficando em linha, já tentei diversas maneiras para tentar inserir uma embaixo da outra, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O correto seria ficar no formato abaixo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -50;
  padding: 0; 
}

.jumbo {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/300);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
  align-items: center;  
  padding-top: 12.0cm;
  float:right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.box {
  width: calc(20% - 2rem);
  height: 10rem;
  margin: 1.0em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.p1,
.p2,
.p3 {
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

.p1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color:#DCDCDC;
  color:black;
  position: right;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.p2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  color:#DCDCDC;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca o `.container` com `width: 50%`. Obviamente vc ainda precisa tratar a responsividade para telas menores....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* margin-left: -50; */
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}

.jumbo {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/600/300);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%
}

.container {
 /* width: 100%; */
  align-items: center;  
  padding-top: 12.0cm;
  float:right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: right;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 1rem;


  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;

}

.box {
  width: calc(20% - 2rem);
  height: 10rem;
  margin: 1.0em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.p1,
.p2,
.p3 {
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

.p1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color:#DCDCDC;
  color:black;
  position: right;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.p2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  color:#DCDCDC;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, peguei seu código e fiz alguns ajustes para você ter uma caminho.
Da uma olhada em display grid e display flex.

```
 <div class="jumbo">
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="p1">
      100%
    </div>
    <div class="p2">
      SAMSUNG
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="box">
    <div class="p1">
      100%
    </div>
    <div class="p2">
      SAMSUNG
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="p1">
      100%
    </div>
    <div class="p2">
      SAMSUNG
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="p1">
      100%
    </div>
    <div class="p2">
      SAMSUNG
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

E o CSS:

```
 html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.jumbo {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10rem;
  margin: 1.0em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.p1,
.p2,
.p3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}

.p1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  color: black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.p2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  color: #DCDCDC;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

Exemplo rodando: https://jsfiddle.net/ec2f14q7/

Bons estudos!

Answer (score 0):

Oi Gabriel Paixão Justino, tudo certo?  Você precisa pegar o box das marcas ( Samsung,asus,dell..) e colocar dentro de um col-6 e o outro lado dentro de outro col- 6 porem tudo isso dentro de um row. Olha a alteração que fiz no seu HTML, espero ter ajudado.

```html
<div class="jumbo">
  <div class="container row">
    <div class="box col-md-6">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        50%
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        100%
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        SAMSUNG
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O que é col-6? Eu não via nada no CSS dele, nem no seu

Comment: Oi,  Caetano Sincero, col-6 é bootstrap, olha a terceira linha <div class="box col-md-6"> .
Uma boa referência: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/default.asp